# Drag and drop on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

It is not related to changing order in RecyclerView question and I didn't find satisfying example.

Let's say we want to put apple to one of the boxes. In our application we have ImageView on the top which represents apple, and boxes below. These boxes are just RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.

First we set onTouchListener on apple:

```
appleImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
             view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
             view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             return true;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
   }
});
```

Now we set OnDragListener on our container which contains RecyclerView (or can we set on RecyclerView?):

```
containerLayout.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      final View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
          break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
          break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          // HERE IS INTERESTING PART
          break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
          break;
      default:
          break;
      }
      return true;
  }
});
```

The question is:

**How can we get RecyclerView item on which drop action was happened?**

I thought maybe we can get coordinates where we dropped appleImageView by calling `event.getX(); event.getY();` but I don't how to get RecyclerView item with screen coordinates.

Comment: Try with  draglistener for each recyclerView item. Set it up in your onBinderView.

Comment: I'll try later, but seems like great idea!